# react native change button states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple buttons that highlights onPress(ON/OFF). What I want to do is that I want to display how many buttons was clicked. The image shows that 4 buttons were selected. I want to change to state to 4 and display it in "selected:4"
[image]

This is my code. But for some reason I can't get it right. When ever I toggle the button, I want the state to correspond.

```
state={
    toogle:true,
    count:0
  }

  _onPress() {
    const newState = !this.state.toggle
    this.setState({ toggle: newState })

    const count = this.state.count
    this.setState({count:count})

    this.props.onStateChange && this.props.onStateChange(this.state.count)
    if(this.state.toogle = true ){this.handleIncrement()}
    else if (this.state.toogle = false){this.handleDecrement()}

  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
     this.setState({
         count: this.state.count + 1
     });
    }
    handleDecrement = () => {
       this.setState({
         count: this.state.count - 1
       });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can make a incrementerMethod and call it on each click**

```js
icrementer(){
var Count=this.state.count;
this.setState({count:Count+1})
}
```

Comment: Where do I call this method? in the `_onPress` method?

Comment: call it on each button click. it'll update total click count.